# Detecting content parsers

Tags: parsing, .htaccess, detection

Is there a way to detect if someone is trying to parse your content with tools like [Simple Html Dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) so i can properly redirect those requests via .htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess not -- all of these kinds of libraries happen client-side, so the request to your server is just a HTTP request like any browser would make.  There might be some oddities in the request headers, but any diligent programmer could mimic what a common browser does and hide behind that.